# Undesired rounding of DateTime in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, datetime, rounding

I ran into something that seems odd. SQL Server appears to be rounding some `DateTime` values inappropriately when I save them to `datetime` columns. I suspect I'm missing something, but I can't spot it. I'm running this test against SQL Server 2008 using .NET 4.0. The following should illustrate the issue:

I have created a table in in SQL Server called Timestamps. It has two columns:

**id** - bigint, Identity, PK
**timestamp** - datetime

I also created a simple test that does the following:

1. Gets the current time, truncating the value to millisecond precision
2. Saved the truncated time to `Timestamps`
3. Retrieved the datetime` value from the DB and compared it to the original (truncated) DateTime object.

```
public static void RoundTest()
{
    DateTime preTruncation = DateTime.UtcNow;
    DateTime truncated = preTruncation.TruncateToMilliseconds();

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["test"].ConnectionString))
    {
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO Timestamps(timestamp) 
                                            VALUES(@savedTime); 
                                            SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS id");
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("savedTime", truncated));
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        var id = cmd.ExecuteScalar();

        SqlCommand get = new SqlCommand(@"SELECT timestamp FROM Timestamps 
                                            WHERE id = @id");

        get.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("id", id));
        get.Connection = conn;
        DateTime retrieved = (DateTime)get.ExecuteScalar();

        if (retrieved != truncated)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("original: " + preTruncation.TimeOfDay);
            Console.WriteLine("truncated: " + truncated.TimeOfDay);
            Console.WriteLine("retrieved: " + retrieved.TimeOfDay);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Although I expect the truncated value to be equivalent to the value returned back from the DB, that is not always the case.  Here's some sample output:

```
original: 19:59:13.4049965
truncated: 19:59:13.4040000
retrieved: 19:59:13.4030000

original: 19:59:14.4989965
truncated: 19:59:14.4980000
retrieved: 19:59:14.4970000

original: 19:59:15.4749965
truncated: 19:59:15.4740000
retrieved: 19:59:15.4730000

original: 19:59:30.1549965
truncated: 19:59:30.1540000
retrieved: 19:59:30.1530000
```

`TruncateToMilliseconds()` looks like this:

```
public static DateTime TruncateToMilliseconds(this DateTime t)
{
    return new DateTime(t.Year, t.Month, t.Day, t.Hour, t.Minute, t.Second, t.Millisecond);
}
```

What gives?  Is this really inappropriate rounding, or am I making a mistaken assumption here?

Comment: Apparently the SQL standard is rounding (not truncating)... which is horror, because it leads to unintentional datetimes in the future. Even if the same server then queries "everything _not_ in the future", its just-determined and just-inserted datetime (which by definition we would not consider to be in the future) may be excluded.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Datetime is only accurate to 3ms. Therefore it'll round to the nearest multiple of 3ms. To overcome this, look at the [datetime2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335.aspx). Note that this is for SQL2008+ only

EDIT: it's not quite only to 3ms. It's rounded to increments of of .000, .003, or .007 seconds

Comment: Actually, it stores a datetime in two 4 byte integers, the first one representing the date, and the second 4 byte integer  representing the number of clock ticks since midnight. (about 3.33 milleseconds each)

Comment: Correct. Ends up being .003, .007 or .000

Comment: Thanks!  I just assumed that datetime was accurate to 1ms, since it has 1ms precision.