# How to obtain the start time and end time of a day?

Tags: java, date

How to obtain the start time and end time of a day?

code like this is not accurate:

```
 private Date getStartOfDay(Date date) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DATE);
    calendar.set(year, month, day, 0, 0, 0);
    return calendar.getTime();
}

private Date getEndOfDay(Date date) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DATE);
    calendar.set(year, month, day, 23, 59, 59);
    return calendar.getTime();
}
```

It is not accurate to the millisecond.

Comment: What do you mean it's "not accurate"?

Comment: What's wrong with the code?  What are you getting that you don't expect?  What time zone do you want your days to start and end according to?

Comment: The code above does not even use the date passed into the method.  It should be doing: calendar.setTime( date ) after the calendar is created.

Comment: This question assumes date-time values have a resolution of milliseconds. True for java.util.Date and Joda-Time. But False for java.time package in Java 8 (nanoseconds), some databases such as [Postgres](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html) (microseconds), unix libraries (whole seconds), and perhaps others. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20536041/642706) for safer approach using Half-Open.

Comment: The start of day is totally accurate to the mili. FOr the end of day why not just to TimeUnit.DAYS.toMiliseconds(1) - 1l to get the end of the day. Quite literally 'start of next day minus one' . Easy.

Comment: Actually you should get the beginning of the next day and when iterating the items in that day (assuming you want to do that) you will specify the upper bound by using < instead of <=. That would exclude the next day but include all of the previous day down to the nanosecond.

Comment: new Date(epochMillis).toInstant().truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.DAYS).plus(1, ChronoUnit.DAYS)

Answer (score 173, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate                       // Represents an entire day, without time-of-day and without time zone.
.now(                           // Capture the current date.
    ZoneId.of( "Asia/Tokyo" )   // Returns a `ZoneId` object.
)                               // Returns a `LocalDate` object.
.atStartOfDay(                  // Determines the first moment of the day as seen on that date in that time zone. Not all days start at 00:00!
    ZoneId.of( "Asia/Tokyo" ) 
)                               // Returns a `ZonedDateTime` object.
```

## Start of day

Get the full length of the today as seen in a time zone.

Using Half-Open approach, where the beginning is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*. This approach solves the flaw in your code that fails to account for the very last second of the day.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ;
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( zoneId  ) ;

ZonedDateTime zdtStart = today.atStartOfDay( zoneId ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdtStop = today.plusDays( 1 ).atStartOfDay( zoneId ) ;
```

> zdtStart.toString() = 2020-01-30T00:00+01:00[Africa/Tunis]

> zdtStop.toString() = 2020-01-31T00:00+01:00[Africa/Tunis]

See the same moments in UTC.

```
Instant start = zdtStart.toInstant() ;
Instant stop = zdtStop.toInstant() ;
```

> start.toString() = 2020-01-29T23:00:00Z

> stop.toString() = 2020-01-30T23:00:00Z

If you want the entire day of a date as seen in UTC rather than in a time zone, use `OffsetDateTime`.

```
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( ZoneOffset.UTC  ) ;

OffsetDateTime odtStart = today.atTime( OffsetTime.MIN ) ;
OffsetDateTime odtStop = today.plusDays( 1 ).atTime( OffsetTime.MIN ) ;
```

> odtStart.toString() = 2020-01-30T00:00+18:00

> odtStop.toString() = 2020-01-31T00:00+18:00

These `OffsetDateTime`  objects will already be in UTC, but you can call `toInstant` if you need such objects which are always in UTC by definition.

```
Instant start = odtStart.toInstant() ;
Instant stop = odtStop.toInstant() ;
```

> start.toString() = 2020-01-29T06:00:00Z

> stop.toString() = 2020-01-30T06:00:00Z

Tip: You may be interested in adding the [*ThreeTen-Extra*](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) library to your project to use its [`Interval`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html) class to represent this pair of `Instant` objects. This class offers useful methods for comparison such as `abuts`, `overlaps`, `contains`, and more.

```
Interval interval = Interval.of( start , stop ) ;
```

> interval.toString() = 2020-01-29T06:00:00Z/2020-01-30T06:00:00Z

## Half-Open

The [answer by mprivat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10308430/642706) is correct. His point is to not try to obtain end of a day, but rather compare to "before start of next day". His idea is known as the "Half-Open" approach where a span of time has a **beginning that is inclusive** while the **ending is exclusive**.

- The current date-time frameworks of Java (java.util.Date/Calendar and [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/)) both use milliseconds from the [epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_%28reference_date%29). But in Java 8, the new JSR 310 java.time.* classes use nanoseconds resolution. Any code you wrote based on forcing the milliseconds count of last moment of day would be incorrect if switched to the new classes.
- Comparing data from other sources becomes faulty if they employ other resolutions. For example, Unix libraries typically employ whole seconds, and databases such as [Postgres](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html) resolve date-time to microseconds.
- Some Daylight Saving Time changes happen over midnight which might further confuse things.

[image]

[Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) 2.3 offers a method for this very purpose, to obtain first moment of the day: [`withTimeAtStartOfDay()`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#withTimeAtStartOfDay()). Similarly in java.time, `LocalDate::atStartOfDay`.

[Search StackOverflow for "joda half-open"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=joda+half-open) to see more discussion and examples.

See this post, [Time intervals and other ranges should be half-open](http://wrschneider.blogspot.com/2014/01/time-intervals-and-other-ranges-should.html), by Bill Schneider.

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

The java.util.Date and .Calendar classes are notoriously troublesome. Avoid them.

Use [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. The *java.time* framework is the official successor of the highly successful [*Joda-Time*](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library.

## java.time

The java.time framework is built into Java 8 and later. Back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in the [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project, further adapted to Android in the [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project.

An [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) is a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond).

```
Instant instant = Instant.now();
```

Apply a time zone to get the [wall-clock time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall-clock_time) for some locality.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant( instant , zoneId );
```

To get the first moment of the day go through the [`LocalDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class and its [`atStartOfDay`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#atStartOfDay-java.time.ZoneId-) method.

```
ZonedDateTime zdtStart = zdt.toLocalDate().atStartOfDay( zoneId );
```

Using Half-Open approach, get first moment of following day.

```
ZonedDateTime zdtTomorrowStart = zdtStart.plusDays( 1 );
```

[image: Table of all date-time types in Java, both modern and legacy]

Currently the java.time framework lacks an `Interval` class as described below for Joda-Time. However, the [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is the proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. Among its classes is [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html). Construct an `Interval` by passing a pair of `Instant` objects. We can extract an `Instant` from our `ZonedDateTime` objects.

```
Interval today = Interval.of( zdtStart.toInstant() , zdtTomorrowStart.toInstant() );
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - [**Java 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) brought some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android (26+) bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), a process known as [*API desugaring*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring) brings a [subset of the *java.time*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) functionality not originally built into Android.

    - If the desugaring does not offer what you need, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above) to Android. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

---

## Joda-Time

UPDATE: The Joda-Time project is now in maintenance-mode, and advises migration to the *java.time* classes. I am leaving this section intact for history.

Joda-Time has three classes to represent a span of time in various ways: `Interval`, `Period`, and `Duration`. An `Interval` has a specific beginning and ending on the timeline of the Universe. This fits our need to represent "a day".

We call the method `withTimeAtStartOfDay` rather than set time of day to zeros. Because of Daylight Saving Time and other anomalies the first moment of the day may not be `00:00:00`.

Example code using Joda-Time 2.3.

```
DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Montreal" );
DateTime now = DateTime.now( timeZone );
DateTime todayStart = now.withTimeAtStartOfDay();
DateTime tomorrowStart = now.plusDays( 1 ).withTimeAtStartOfDay();
Interval today = new Interval( todayStart, tomorrowStart );
```

If you must, you can convert to a java.util.Date.

```
java.util.Date date = todayStart.toDate();
```

Comment: I need to use `LocalDateTime`

Comment: But what if I do need the very last nanosecond of the day using just java.time? What should I do? Use the accepted answer, the comment in the accepted answer that states that we should code `.plusDays(1).atStartOfDay().minusNanos(1)` or something else?

Comment: @PhilippeGioseffi No, you would never need to know the last minute/second/nanosecond. All that you need to know is the *first moment of the following day*. If you want to know if a moment occurs by the end of tomorrow: `myInstant.isBefore( LocalDate.now( zoneId ).plusDays( 2 ).atStartOfDay( zoneId ).toInstant() )`. Notice we added *two* days, to get past tomorrow, to the first moment of the day after tomorrow. I suggest you shift your thinking to the Half-Open approach. Date-time handling is much easier, and less error-prone, with Half-Open.

Comment: @BasilBourque, I've been reading about this specific subject and got convinced that you're right. In addition to that, the user accepted the solution using with just the last second of the day.

Answer (score 234):

### Java 8

---

```
public static Date atStartOfDay(Date date) {
    LocalDateTime localDateTime = dateToLocalDateTime(date);
    LocalDateTime startOfDay = localDateTime.with(LocalTime.MIN);
    return localDateTimeToDate(startOfDay);
}

public static Date atEndOfDay(Date date) {
    LocalDateTime localDateTime = dateToLocalDateTime(date);
    LocalDateTime endOfDay = localDateTime.with(LocalTime.MAX);
    return localDateTimeToDate(endOfDay);
}

private static LocalDateTime dateToLocalDateTime(Date date) {
    return LocalDateTime.ofInstant(date.toInstant(), ZoneId.systemDefault());
}

private static Date localDateTimeToDate(LocalDateTime localDateTime) {
    return Date.from(localDateTime.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant());
}
```

**Update**: I've added these 2 methods to my Java Utility Classes [here](https://github.com/RKumsher/utils)

- [DateUtils.atStartOfDay](https://github.com/RKumsher/utils/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/rkumsher/date/DateUtils.java#L47)
- [DateUtils.atEndOfDay](https://github.com/RKumsher/utils/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/rkumsher/date/DateUtils.java#L61)

It is in the Maven Central Repository at:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.github.rkumsher</groupId>
  <artifactId>utils</artifactId>
  <version>1.3</version>
</dependency>
```

### Java 7 and Earlier

---

### With Apache Commons

```
public static Date atEndOfDay(Date date) {
    return DateUtils.addMilliseconds(DateUtils.ceiling(date, Calendar.DATE), -1);
}

public static Date atStartOfDay(Date date) {
    return DateUtils.truncate(date, Calendar.DATE);
}
```

### Without Apache Commons

```
public Date atEndOfDay(Date date) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(date);
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 59);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 999);
    return calendar.getTime();
}

public Date atStartOfDay(Date date) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(date);
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    return calendar.getTime();
}
```

Comment: I recommend against this approach because of the edge case issues you'll run into with time zones, daylight savings, etc. that a time library like Joda will take care of for you.

Comment: I think in `getStartOfDay` should be: `LocalDateTime startOfDay = localDateTime.with(LocalTime.MIN);` I.e. LocalTime, not LocalDateTime.

Comment: Don't think those `getEndOfDay(Date date)`. `getStartOfDay(Date date)` methods in the Java 8 section are correct, namely LocalDateTime.MAX and .MIN put you at the earliest possible dates in the past and in the future, *not* the beginning and ending of a day.  Instead I'd suggest .atStartOfDay() for start and .plusDays(1).atStartOfDay().minusNanos(1) for end.

Comment: Method `localDateTimeToDate(LocalDateTime startOfDay)` throws Exception - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.ArithmeticException: long overflow

Comment: As @KonstantinKulagin said, the answer must be corrected to `LocalDateTime startOfDay = localDateTime.with(LocalTime.MIN);`  Otherwise it fails with error I posted above,

Comment: @GlenMazza the Java 8 solution uses [**LocalTime**.MAX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html#MAX), not [LocalDateTime.MAX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#MAX). The solution is correct.

Comment: Doesn't look like `LocalDateTime` has method `atStartOfDay`

Comment: If you are using this date for a database the without Apache commons methode won't work.

The calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 999); gets rounded,
It should be: calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 997); 
For database the datetime values are rounded to increments of .000, .003, or .007 seconds.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4307635/undesired-rounding-of-datetime-in-sql-server

Answer (score 32):

in getEndOfDay, you can add:

```
calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 999);
```

Although mathematically speaking, you can't specify the end of a day other than by saying it's "before the beginning of the next day".

So instead of saying, `if(date >= getStartOfDay(today) && date <= getEndOfDay(today))`, you should say: `if(date >= getStartOfDay(today) && date < getStartOfDay(tomorrow))`. That is a much more solid definition (and you don't have to worry about millisecond precision).

Comment: The second half of this answer is the best way. This approach is known as "Half-Open". I explain further in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20536041/642706).

Answer (score 21):

## java.time

Using `java.time` framework built into Java 8.

```
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now(); // 2015-11-19T19:42:19.224
// start of a day
now.with(LocalTime.MIN); // 2015-11-19T00:00
now.with(LocalTime.MIDNIGHT); // 2015-11-19T00:00
// end of a day
now.with(LocalTime.MAX); // 2015-11-19T23:59:59.999999999
```

Comment: This Answer ignores anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time (DST). The `Local…` classes have no concept of time zones and adjusting for anomalies. For example, some time zones have a DST change-over at midnight, so the first moment of the day is at the time `01:00:00.0` (1 AM) rather than the `00:00:00.0` value produced by this code. Use `ZonedDateTime` instead.

Answer (score 6):

Additional way of finding start of day with java8 java.time.ZonedDateTime instead of going through `LocalDateTime` is simply truncating the input ZonedDateTime to DAYS:

```
zonedDateTimeInstance.truncatedTo( ChronoUnit.DAYS );
```

Answer (score 6):

#Java 8 or ThreeTenABP

###ZonedDateTime

```
ZonedDateTime curDate = ZonedDateTime.now();

public ZonedDateTime startOfDay() {
    return curDate
    .toLocalDate()
    .atStartOfDay()
    .atZone(curDate.getZone())
    .withEarlierOffsetAtOverlap();
}

public ZonedDateTime endOfDay() {

    ZonedDateTime startOfTomorrow =
        curDate
        .toLocalDate()
        .plusDays(1)
        .atStartOfDay()
        .atZone(curDate.getZone())
        .withEarlierOffsetAtOverlap();

    return startOfTomorrow.minusSeconds(1);
}

// based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/29145886/1658268
```

###LocalDateTime

```
LocalDateTime curDate = LocalDateTime.now();

public LocalDateTime startOfDay() {
    return curDate.atStartOfDay();
}

public LocalDateTime endOfDay() {
    return curDate.atTime(LocalTime.MAX);  //23:59:59.999999999;
}

// based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/36408726/1658268
```

I hope that helps someone.

Comment: The "atTime" method is a very good approach togheter with the constant "LocalTime.MAX" for end of day. Nice!

Comment: I can't find atStartOfDay method in LocalDateTime for java 8

Comment: @sudoplz
please describe startOfTomorrow ?

Comment: @ArnabDutta I changed the code, take a look.

Answer (score 3):

Another one solution which does not depend on any framework is:

```
static public Date getStartOfADay(Date day) {
    final long oneDayInMillis = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
    return new Date(day.getTime() / oneDayInMillis * oneDayInMillis);
}

static public Date getEndOfADay(Date day) {
    final long oneDayInMillis = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
    return new Date((day.getTime() / oneDayInMillis + 1) * oneDayInMillis - 1);
}
```

Note that it returns UTC based time

Answer (score 3):

I tried this code and it works well!

```
final ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC);
final ZonedDateTime startofDay =
    now.toLocalDate().atStartOfDay(ZoneOffset.UTC);
final ZonedDateTime endOfDay =
    now.toLocalDate().atTime(LocalTime.MAX).atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC);
```

Comment: If you have `ZonedDateTime` and `Instant` at your disposal there is no need to ever use `java.sql.Timestamp`. That class is one of the terrible old legacy classes now supplanted by the *java.time* classes. As of JDBC 4.2, we can directly exchange *java.time* objects with the database. Your mixing of the legacy and modern classes makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 3):

```
private Instant getStartOfDay() {
    return Instant.now().truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.DAYS);
}

private Instant getEndOfDay() {
    return Instant.now()
            .plus(1, ChronoUnit.DAYS)
            .truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.DAYS)
            .minusNanos(1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For java 8 the following single line statements are working. In this example I use UTC timezone. Please consider to change TimeZone that you currently used.

```js
System.out.println(new Date());

final LocalDateTime endOfDay       = LocalDateTime.of(LocalDate.now(), LocalTime.MAX);
final Date          endOfDayAsDate = Date.from(endOfDay.toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC));

System.out.println(endOfDayAsDate);

final LocalDateTime startOfDay       = LocalDateTime.of(LocalDate.now(), LocalTime.MIN);
final Date          startOfDayAsDate = Date.from(startOfDay.toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC));

System.out.println(startOfDayAsDate);
```

If no time difference with output. Try: `ZoneOffset.ofHours(0)`

Comment: How does this add value beyond that of the existing Answers? Also, you ignore the crucial issue of time zone. And passing the UTC constant to `toInstant` is illegal syntax and redundant conceptually.

Comment: @BasilBourque "How does this add value beyond that of the existing Answers?" This is how stackoverflow works. BTW this is just a template. People can change the way they want. passing UTC to toInstant is totally legal you can examine the outputs.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's a bit late, but in case of Java 8, if you are using OffsetDateTime (which offers a lot of advantages, such as TimeZone, Nanoseconds, etc.), you can use the following code:

```
OffsetDateTime reallyEndOfDay = someDay.withHour(23).withMinute(59).withSecond(59).withNano(999999999);
// output: 2019-01-10T23:59:59.999999999Z
```

Answer (score 2):

```
private Date getStartOfDay(Date date) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DATE);
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(0);
    calendar.set(year, month, day, 0, 0, 0);
    return calendar.getTime();
    }

private Date getEndOfDay(Date date) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DATE);
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(0);
    calendar.set(year, month, day, 23, 59, 59);
    return calendar.getTime();
    }
```

**calendar.setTimeInMillis(0);** gives you accuracy upto milliseconds

Comment: These terrible date-time classes were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Comment: @BasilBourque the package _java.time_ only appeared in Java 8 which is available only since Android N (API 26)

Comment: @ivan8m8  Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in the *ThreeTen-Backport* library. Further adapted for early Android (<26) in the *ThreeTenABP* library.

Comment: @BasilBourque but the ThreeTen uses _an extremely inefficient mechanism on Android_.

Comment: @ivan8m8  You may be thinking of the predecessor of *java.time*, *Joda-Time*. Again, see the [*ThreeTenABP*](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project. I’ve not heard of such inefficiency on Android using that library.

Answer (score 2):

Shortest answer, given your timezone being `TZ`:

```
LocalDateTime start = LocalDate.now(TZ).atStartOfDay()
LocalDateTime end = start.plusDays(1)
```

Compare using `isAfter()` and `isBefore()` methods, or convert it using `toEpochSecond()` or `toInstant()` methods.

Answer (score 1):

The following code takes the OP's original formula, and adjusts for the ms inexactness:

```
    private static Date getStartOfDay() {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DATE);
        calendar.set(year, month, day, 0, 0, 0);
        long approximateTimestamp = calendar.getTime().getTime();
        long extraMillis = (approximateTimestamp % 1000);
        long exactTimestamp = approximateTimestamp - extraMillis;
        return new Date(exactTimestamp);
    }

    private static Date getEndOfDay() {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DATE);
        calendar.set(year, month, day, 23, 59, 59);
        long approximateTimestamp = calendar.getTime().getTime();
        long extraMillis = (approximateTimestamp % 1000);
        long exactTimestamp = approximateTimestamp - extraMillis + 999;
        return new Date(exactTimestamp);
    }
```

Unlike many other answers on this thread, it is compatible with older versions of Java and Android APIs.

Answer (score 0):

I had several inconveniences with all the solutions because I needed the type of **Instant** variable and the Time Zone always interfered changing everything, then combining solutions I saw that this is a good option.

```
        LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
        Instant startDate = Instant.parse(today.toString()+"T00:00:00Z");
        Instant endDate = Instant.parse(today.toString()+"T23:59:59Z");
```

and we have as a result

```
        startDate = 2020-01-30T00:00:00Z
        endDate = 2020-01-30T23:59:59Z
```

I hope it helps you

Comment: The day actually ends at the arrival of the first moment of the *following* day. Your code skips over the last full second of a day, a billion nanoseconds that are never reported. See [my Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20536041/642706) to learn about Half-Open approach to defining a span-of-time.

Comment: Manipulating strings as a way of handling date-time values is generally a poor approach. Use smart objects rather than dumb strings for this work. The *java.time* classes give all the functionality you need for this problem without resorting to string manipulation.

Comment: I just now added a *tl;dr* section to [my Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20536041/642706) showing how to get the range of a day as a pair of `Instant` objects. Tip: you may be interested in adding the *ThreeTen-Extra* library to your project to use its `Interval` class.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest would be something like:

```
// Joda Time

DateTime dateTime=new DateTime(); 

StartOfDayMillis = dateTime.withMillis(System.currentTimeMillis()).withTimeAtStartOfDay().getMillis();
EndOfDayMillis = dateTime.withMillis(StartOfDayMillis).plusDays(1).minusSeconds(1).getMillis();
```

These millis can be then converted into Calendar,Instant or LocalDate as per your requirement with Joda Time.

Answer (score -2):

```
public static Date beginOfDay(Date date) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(date);
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

    return cal.getTime();
}

public static Date endOfDay(Date date) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(date);
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 59);
    cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 999);

    return cal.getTime();
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
Date date = new Date();
LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(date.toInstant(), ZoneId.systemDefault());
LocalDateTime startOfDay = localDateTime.with(LocalTime.MIN);
LocalDateTime endOfDay = localDateTime.with(LocalTime.MAX);
```

Timestamp:

```
Timestamp startTs = Timestamp.valueOf(startOfDay);
Timestamp endTs = Timestamp.valueOf(endOfDay);
```

Comment: java.util.Date is deprecated see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5677470/java-why-is-the-date-constructor-deprecated-and-what-do-i-use-instead