# How to get system date with time 00:00:00

Tags: java, android

Is it possible to get system date with time 00:00:00,below is the code i am using--

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy");
java.util.Date date3 = new java.util.Date();
output-Thu jul 10 10:31:12 EDT 2014
```

I want the result like this----Thu jul 10 00:00:00 EDT 2014

it should be in Date format not in String.
please help me out.

Comment: see this http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to obtain the start time and end time of a day?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10308356/how-to-obtain-the-start-time-and-end-time-of-a-day)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Try setting

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy");
java.util.Date date3 = new java.util.Date();
date3.setHours(0);
date3.setMinutes(0);
date3.setSeconds(0);
```

Comment: do not recommend deprecated methods

Comment: @user3823948 These methods have been deprecated since version 1.1 - do not use this way.

Answer (score 4):

You can use calendar object to set the time.

```
Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(date3);
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
```

Comment: still the `DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy");` will be wrong

Comment: @ScaryWombat maybe it should be DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy");

Comment: No, it OP wants 00:00:00 to appear

Answer (score 0):

a quick and dirty solution

```
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd 00:00:00 yyyy");
    System.out.println(dateFormat.format (new Date ()));
```

as the API page

You can insert your own text into the pattern

```
"yyyy.MM.dd G 'at' HH:mm:ss z"  2001.07.04 AD at 12:08:56 PDT
```