# How to obtain the end of the day when given a LocalDate?

Tags: java, java-time

How to obtain the end of the day when given a LocalDate?

I could get it by doing

```
LocalDateTime.of(LocalDate.now(), LocalTime.of(23, 59, 59));
```

But is there an equivalent 'atStartOfDay' method for the end of the day?

```
LocalDate.now().atStartOfDay();
LocalDate.now().atEndOfDay(); //doesn't work
```

Comment: What do you mean by "end of the day"? The start of the following day minus 1 second? 1 millisecond? 1 nanosecond? Why not just use the beginning of the next day, and use `[day, day + 1[` intervals? When a shop is open from 8AM to 6PM, the end time displayed is 6PM, not 5:59:59 PM.

Comment: This answer also contains a solution for a ZonedDateTime https://stackoverflow.com/a/50400321/1658268

Answer (score 183, accepted):

Here are a few alternatives, depending on what you need:

```
LocalDate.now().atTime(23, 59, 59);     //23:59:59
LocalDate.now().atTime(LocalTime.MAX);  //23:59:59.999999999
```

But there is no built-in method.

As commented by @JBNizet, if you want to create an interval, you can also use an interval up to midnight, exclusive.

Comment: What about daylight saving time?

Comment: @MateusViccari LocalDate / LocalDateTime have no time zone so no DST rule. Not sure what you are asking about.

Answer (score 56):

These are the variants available in [`LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html#field.summary), notice `MIDNIGHT` and `MIN` are equal.

```
LocalDate.now().atTime(LocalTime.MIDNIGHT); //00:00:00.000000000
LocalDate.now().atTime(LocalTime.MIN);      //00:00:00.000000000
LocalDate.now().atTime(LocalTime.NOON);     //12:00:00.000000000
LocalDate.now().atTime(LocalTime.MAX);      //23:59:59.999999999
```

For reference, this is the implementation in `java.time.LocalTime`

```
/**
 * Constants for the local time of each hour.
 */
private static final LocalTime[] HOURS = new LocalTime[24];
static {
    for (int i = 0; i < HOURS.length; i++) {
        HOURS[i] = new LocalTime(i, 0, 0, 0);
    }
    MIDNIGHT = HOURS[0];
    NOON = HOURS[12];
    MIN = HOURS[0];
    MAX = new LocalTime(23, 59, 59, 999_999_999);
}
```

If the value assigned to the 4th constructor argument (`999_999_999`) of `LocalTime` (representing `nanoOfSecond`) looks unfamiliar it's because it's making use of the Java 7 feature [Underscores in Numeric Literals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/underscores-literals.html).

> In Java SE 7 and later, any number of underscore characters (_) can appear anywhere between digits in a numerical literal. This feature enables you, for example, to separate groups of digits in numeric literals, which can improve the readability of your code.

Answer (score 8):

Get start of next day and subtract 1 second from it. This should work for you. :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();
    LocalDateTime dt = date.atStartOfDay().plusDays(1).minusSeconds(1);
    System.out.println(dt);
}
```

O/P :

```
2016-04-04T23:59:59
```

Comment: note this is 1 second, not one millisecond, I would advise against this hack

Comment: this is brilliant !!

Comment: This will get you only the time at 23:59:59.000000000. So if you use this solution you should be aware of that. It's safer to use the accepted answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36408726/2294031

Answer (score 1):

```
public static long getStartOfDay(String country) {
    return LocalDate.now().atStartOfDay(ZoneId.of("Europe/Berlin")).toInstant().toEpochMilli();
}

public static long getEndOfDay(long startOfDay) {
    return startOfDay + 86399000L;  // adding 24h = 1day seconds - 1
}

public static long getStartOfDay(LocalDate localDate, String country) {
    return localDate.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.of("Europe/Berlin")).toInstant().toEpochMilli();
}

public static long getEndOfDay(LocalDate localDate, String country) {
    localDate = localDate.plusDays(1L);
    return localDate.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.of("Europe/Berlin")).toInstant().toEpochMilli() - 1000L; //substract mili
}
```