# How to cast date and time in Android

Tags: java, android, date, android-calendar

In my application i want get some data from server and i should cast date and time!
I receive date and time with this format `end_date: "2020-04-08 13:11:14"` from server.

I want get now date and time from my device and to calculate with above date (**end_date**), if this time **under 24h** i should show for example **15 hour later**, but if this time **more than 24h** i should show **2 days later**!

But i don't know how can i it?
Can you help me with send code or send to me other tutorials?!
I searched that but I didn't find anything.

Comment: What did your search turn up? You have searched before asking, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## *java.time*

The modern approach uses *java.time* classes.

[image: Table of date-time types in Java, both modern and legacy]

Parse the input string as a [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html).

To parse, replace the SPACE in the middle with a `T` to comply with [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard.

```
String input = "2020-04-08 13:11:14".replace( " " , "T" ) ;
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input ) ;
```

Your input lacks an indicator of any time zone or offset-from-UTC. So we do not know if this was meant to be 1 PM in Tokyo Japan, 1 PM in Toulouse France, or 1 PM in Toledo Ohio US. So you cannot reliably compare this to the current date and time.

If you want to *presume* this string was meant to tell time in your time zone, then assign a time zone to get a [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Tokyo" ) ;
ZonedDateTime then = ldt.atZone( z ) ;
```

Capture the current moment in the same zone.

```
ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;
```

Calculate 24 hours later.

```
ZonedDateTime twentyFourHoursFuture = now.plusHours( 24 ) ;
```

Compare.

```
boolean within24Hours = then.isBefore( twentyFourHoursFuture ) ;
```

Determine elapsed time using the [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html) class.

```
Duration duration = Duration.between( then , now ) ;
```

If you want to trust the JVM’s current default time zone, call `ZoneId.systemDefault`. Beware that this default can be changed by other Java code *during* execution of your app.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.systemDefault() ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [datetime](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_date.asp) library, or you can see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10308356/how-to-obtain-the-start-time-and-end-time-of-a-day).

Also if you can choose, it's a good habit to pass the times in UTC from/to the server, it'll save some localization and timezone troubles.

Comment: Thanks, but can you send to me code? because i am amateur and really need your help. please dear