# Does ::TIMESTAMP::DATE work in Java/Spring?

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have this code that runs a query in PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT planned,COUNT(*) AS results
FROM dashboard.event
WHERE event_start_adj::TIMESTAMP::DATE = '2020-04-05'
GROUP BY planned
```

This code actually works but the problem is when i insert this to Java Spring like this:

[image]

it gives me an error like this:

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near ":"
> Position: 80

I've tried removing it to `event_start_adj =`  But it returns nothing since the data of my event_start_adj in PostgreSQL is `timestamp without time zone` That's why the query above extracts the date first. How can I fix this?

Comment: Please do **not** post code as images. See here for more details why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obfuscation layers like JPA can't properly handle the `::` operator, you need to rewrite it to use the CAST() operator instead:

```
WHERE cast(cast(event_start_adj as TIMESTAMP) as DATE) = '2020-04-05'
```

However if `event_start_adj` is already a `timestamp` the first case is useless, so it seems the following should be enough:

```
WHERE cast(event_start_adj as DATE) = '2020-04-05'
```

---

Unrelated to the problem at hand, but the expression you are using can't make use of an index on `event_start_adj`. So from a performance point of view, not casting at all would be better, but then you need to change the query to:

```
WHERE event_start_adj => date '2020-04-05'
  AND event_start_adj < date '2020-04-06'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE timestamp_column::::DATE = '2020-04-05'
```

The above worked for me in springboot native query.