# How to convert varchar unixcode to a timestamp in SQL

Tags: sql, presto

I am trying to change the format of a time that I have stored in my database. Currently, the time is stored as such.

```
time           date
1300        2020-06-01
1310        2020-06-01
1315        2020-06-01
```

and I would ideally like to get an output that looks like this as a datestamp

```
time
2020-06-01 13:00:00.000
2020-06-01 13:10:00.000
2020-06-01 13:15:00.000
```

Is there a function to help in making this conversion?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to obtain the start time and end time of a day?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10308356/how-to-obtain-the-start-time-and-end-time-of-a-day)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [date_parse](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#date_parse) function.

```sql
select date_parse(date || ' ' || time, '%Y-%m-%d %H%i') from 
(values ('1300', '2020-06-01')) as t(time, date)
```