# Using convert in SQL Server returns a wrong number of milliseconds

Tags: sql-server, date

Why in SQL Server if I do this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, '2020-06-23 23:21:22.302', 121)
```

I get this date:

```
2020-06-23 23:21:22.303
```

Comment: Try `datetime2(3)` because `datetime` can't store/represent 302 milliseconds.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[see this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4307635/undesired-rounding-of-datetime-in-sql-server)

Its because datetime in SQL Server is only accurate to 3ms and will round to increments of of .000, .003, or .007 seconds

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT convert(datetime, '2020-06-23 23:21:22.302', 121)
SELECT convert(datetime2, '2020-06-23 23:21:22.302', 121)
SELECT convert(datetime2(3), '2020-06-23 23:21:22.302', 121)
```